# how to delete hierarchical parent and child record in store in same table

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchical-data, moodle

```
id name      parentid
 1 category     0
 2 question1    1
 3 type1        2
 4 type2        2
 5 question2    0
 6 type2        5
 7 type2        5
```

Where:

- *category* is parent
- *question1* and *question2* are childs
- *type1*, *type2*, *type3* and *type4* are grandchilds

I want to write a MySQL statement to delete the selected parent with all child records. How can I do that?

Comment: Mr.Nabil, why not have separate tables for parents, children and grand children, considering the future will come to put the past in the casket?. Be prepared.

Comment: hye beck..this is default table created in moodle..so i just follow the db structure..

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support recursive queries...

IF you have a predetermined depth you could do it with a few joins.

Otherwise you will need to do it in code within your application, or write a Stored Proc/Function to do it.

EDIT: quick recursive function to delete...

```
function recursiveDelete($id) {
    $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE parentid='$id'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)>0) {
         while($current=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
              recursiveDelete($current['id']);
         }
    }
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM yourTable WHERE id='$id'");
}
```

Comment: Just thought I'd mention - the solution below (by Ruben) will also work. Just depends on you're preferred approach.

Comment: I think there is significant difference in performance (many queries to DB or one query). But some database engines don't support foreign key. So Brian's solution is more generic.

Comment: i already try it. look like parent and child already deleted in UI but in database only the parent had been delete..it is weird! i mean when i delete question1, in UI the type1 and type2 also disappeared but in database type1 and type2 still there only category1 deleted..

Answer (score 0):

You can create foreign key to support this.

In MySQL this operation looks like:

```
ALTER TABLE your_table_name ADD CONSTRAINT your_table_name_parentid_to_id
FOREIGN KEY (parentid)
REFERENCES your_table_name (id)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Then simply

```
DELETE FROM your_table_name WHERE id = 2;
```

will delete question1, type1 and type2.

But in this case be sure, that for each parentid value there is equal id value or that parentid is NULL:

```
   id  name      parentid
   1   category     NULL
   2   question1    1
   3   type1        2
   4   type2        2
   5   question2    1
   6   type2        5
   7   type2        5
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`connect by` feature in Oracle](http://psoug.org/reference/connectby.html)?